# Installing Grafana custom plugins

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

Please, I installed grafana toolkit to scaffold building custom plugins.
But I don't seem to find the plugins installed on the dashboard.

Comment: What is your grafana setup, what plugin did you install, do you see it in https://{URL}/plugins

Comment: Thanks. I got that fixed but facing another problem.
Now if try installing the grafana toolkit it keeps throwing error.